# How can I use a foreach loop inside my function?

Tags: php, function, foreach

I have a function:

```
   function animals($a,$b,$c,$d){
        $pdo = Database::connect(); 
        $sql = 'SELECT  *  FROM animals ORDER BY id DESC';
        foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
            echo "<td>".$a."</td>"; 
            echo "<td>".$b."</td>"; 
            echo "<td>".$c."</td>"; 
            echo "<td>".$d."</td>"; 
        }   
    }
```

My problem is, I need to use the function multiple times with different amounts of parameters. This means in my foreach loop, sometimes there are 4 items...

```
 animals($row['a'],$row['b'],$row['c'],$row['d'],);
```

... sometimes there are 6 items...

```
  animals($row['e'],$row['f'],$row['g'],$row['h'],$row['i'],$row['j']);
```

... or sometimes 3...

```
animals($row['k'],$row['l'],$row['m']);
```

...and so on. So I am not sure how to tell my function, that the amount of my foreach items vary

---

To be more specific, if I do not use a function my page would look like this:

```
     $pdo = Database::connect(); 
            $sql = 'SELECT  *  FROM animals ORDER BY id DESC';

    <div>

      <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
<?php
           foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                echo "<td>".$a."</td>"; 
                echo "<td>".$b."</td>"; 
                echo "<td>".$c."</td>"; 
                echo "<td>".$d."</td>"; 
            } 

?>  
    </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
<?php
           foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                echo "<td>".$row['a']."</td>"; 
                echo "<td>".$row['b']."</td>"; 
                echo "<td>".$row['c']."</td>"; 
                echo "<td>".$row['d']."</td>"; 
            } 

?>  
    </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">
<?php
           foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                echo "<td>".$row['e']."</td>"; 
                echo "<td>".$row['f']."</td>"; 
                echo "<td>".$row['g']."</td>"; 
                echo "<td>".$row['h']."</td>"; 
            } 

?>  
    </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">
<?php
           foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                echo "<td>".$row['i']."</td>"; 
                echo "<td>".$row['j']."</td>";  
            } 

?>  
    </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: why you passing arguments if you still running query in function?

Comment: @RakeshSharma What is an arg?

Comment: @DsRaj No, there is only one id

Comment: Show code where you calling function and passing $a, $b..... etc. and how you getting these variables

Comment: @RakeshSharma I did in my question:  `animals($row['a'],$row['b'],$row['c'],$row['d'],);`

Comment: @Jarla :  can you also share your html table where I think you are calling `animals` function  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get array of function arguments with [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php).

```
function animals(){
  $args = func_get_args();

  $pdo = Database::connect(); 
  $sql = 'SELECT  *  FROM animals ORDER BY id DESC';

  foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    foreach ($args as $arg_value) {
      echo "<td>".$arg_value."</td>"; 
    }
  }
}

// Call function
animals(1, 2, 3);
// or 
animals(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

**EDIT**

I guess that you just want to print certains fields from `$row`?

```
function animals(){
  $args = func_get_args();

  foreach ($args as $arg_value) {
    echo "<td>".$arg_value."</td>"; 
  }
}

$pdo = Database::connect(); 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `animals` ORDER BY id DESC';

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
  animals($row['a'], $row['b'], $row['c']);
  // or
  animals($row['i'], $row['j']);
}
```

And shorter:

```
function animals(){
  $args = func_get_args();

  $pdo = Database::connect(); 
  $sql = 'SELECT `'.implode('`, `', $args).'` FROM `animals` ORDER BY id DESC';

  foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $value) {
      echo "<td>".$value."</td>"; 
    }
  }
}

// Then you can just do
animals('a', 'b', 'c');

// or
animals('i', 'j');
```

Comment: I tested your suggestion, my result is `12312312312312312341234123412341234`. But I expected `1231234`

Comment: I'm not following what you are trying to achieve. Why is there DB query then? Removing DB query and it's `foreach` will result in `1231234`. You are repeating both outputs 5 times because of rows from DB.

Comment: I am confused, how can I remove the database query if the results of my database is what I need

Comment: It dosen't seem like that if you expected `1231234`. Is function arguments animal IDs? What are you exactly setting as arguments?

Comment: in reality it is more complex so I am repeating a really big code again and again, and I thought a function would make it more simple and clear

Comment: I think that I now understand. See my edit, is that wthat you wanted to echieve? This could be even shorter but I will add it if it's correct logic.

Comment: Thank you! I will test it and let you know

Comment: Actually it is working exactly like you suggested. I have now another problem, that I need in the foreach loop another database request, and because of that the function doesn't want to work with my code. But otherwise it is working very well and was what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Okay. Glad I could help. You can always ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to achieve this kind a functionality you need to create a function without arguments and need to use PHP function [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

```
function animals(){
   $arr = func_get_args();
   foreach($arr as $v){
      //
   }
}

animals(1,2,3,4,5);
animals(1,2,3);
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/CcRKp)

Comment: Why not pass an array of result to function rather each vars?

Comment: That can be possible alternative.

Comment: How can I use your suggestion with my database output ` foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {`? Do you mean to have a second foreach loop like Rakesh Sharma suggested?

Comment: I can't suggest anything until and unless you don't specify the use of your query and your variables in your function @Jarla.

Comment: in my sql database I have for example rows like `a`, `b` or `c` and I want to get them inside my foreach loop like for example `foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {echo "$row['a']";}`

Comment: And whats the use of passing variables in a function then?

Comment: Because I need multiple foreach loops on my page and it would be to much code to write all the content again and again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114310/discussion-between-jarla-and-uchiha).

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a full `$row` array to your function and loop over this like

```
function animals($val){
   $pdo = Database::connect(); 
   $sql = 'SELECT  *  FROM animals ORDER BY id DESC';
   foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
     foreach($val as $v){
       echo "<td>".$v."</td>";
     }
   }   
}
```

Then call your function like `animals($row);`

Also if i am not wrong you don't need again query in your function just keep it simple like

```
function animals($val){
    foreach($val as $v){
       echo "<td>".$v."</td>";
     }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use your function, but still have problems. I try to do this, but still cannot get it run: `animals($row['a'],$row['b'],$row['c'],$row['d'])`